# Give the name of customers who bought all products with price less than 5.(NORTHWIND)

Tags: sql, database, t-sql

Hi im trying to learn sql and im using the northwind test database to practice. 
This is how far I have come:

```
select 
    c.CompanyName 
from Customers as c 
inner join Orders as O on > o.OrderID=c.CustomerID 
inner join [Order Details] as OD on > od.ProductID=o.OrderID 
inner join Products as p on > p.ProductID=od.ProductID 
where p.UnitPrice < 5
```

p.s I have more querys I could use some help with if anyone is up for it

Comment: what is the problem/your question? I can see that those > signs would cause syntax errors, just remove them, but otherwise this looks like it could do what you need. you may want to add a `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` to get each customer name only once.

Comment: Problem is that I dont get any results, so I hafto do something wrong, I dont get any error messages but FirstName, LastName, City is empty. Yes the > signs is taken away

Comment: ah probably joining `od.ProductID=o.OrderID` is wrong. there should be an `OrderID` in the `[Order Details]` table as well, as its foreign key, use this one to join. same with `CustomerID` in the first join. create a database diagram of Northwind and study the primary key/foreign key relations to avoid this kind of mistakes. They can get nasty and difficult to diagnose because sometimes you may have matches between unrelated keys, giving entirely chaotic results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you are joing everything with Order ID ?

inner join Orders as O on > **o.OrderID=c.CustomerID**  (Customer ID from both the tables should be joined here)

inner join [Order Details] as OD on  **od.ProductID=o.OrderID**  - (Order ID from master and transaction should be joined)

Comment: this looks like if you intended to subtract CustomerID and OrderID :) be careful not to repeats those > signs, they're not part of any valid join syntax.

Comment: @dlatikay I just wanted to point out columns used for joins..otherwise query is same

Answer (score -1):

Yes your right, now it works thanks!

```
 select c.CompanyName 
 from Customers as c
 inner join Orders as O on o.CustomerID=c.CustomerID
 inner join [Order Details] as OD on od.OrderID=o.OrderID
 inner join Products as p on p.ProductID=od.ProductID
 where p.UnitPrice > 5
```